# Invalid value of MM in source string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract the date out of the orderstatus field in the below table

| orderstatus | orddate | Soldorstockdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *SLD 05/11/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 |
| 37141 SLD BAM | 5/5/2022 | 5/5/2022 |
| *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 5/3/2022 | 5/14/2022 |
| 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 5/18/2022 | 5/18/2022 |
| *SLD BOBBY LANE IDS#2347509 | 5/16/2022 | 5/16/2022 |
| *SLD F.CHAPMAN/S.GUNN 5/31/22 | 5/10/2022 | 5/10/2022 |
| *SLD S.STONE STK# 39391 40183 | 5/5/2022 | 5/5/2022 |

If the pattern *SLD appears at the beginning in the orderstatus column and there is a date of the format mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy then that date needs to be extracted as the soldorstockdate else the orddate should be extracted as the soldorstockdate

I am using the query below

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("ORDERSTATUS",'^\\*SLD') <> 0
         THEN TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR("ORDERSTATUS", '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')
         ELSE DATE("ORDDATE")
END AS ORDERDATE
```

The above queryis working fine except for the values *SLD BOBBY LANE IDS#2347509 , *SLD F.CHAPMAN/S.GUNN 5/31/22 and *SLD S.STONE STK# 39391 40183 due to which I am getting an error "Invalid value of MM in source string"...

If the orderstatus column has *SLD at the beginning and does not have date of the format mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy or/mm/dd then orddate should be extracted as the soldorstockdate for that record..

Any inputs will be appreciated

Also the above query is not picking up *SLD BAM 6/9/22

Comment: So it's erroring when the column doesn't have a valid date format. Can you add another criteria to your case statement, looking for the orderstatus containing /nn/ or /n/ within it's pattern?

Comment: your reg expressioon is wrong first fix that

Comment: @nbk: appreciate your response!...Do you have any inputs on the same...

Comment: yes a date in your case has between montn and year a / your regular expression has no and would so exclude 5 digits, but you need to test that, and of course a Isolator said you need also to test it i the case when

Comment: @Isolated: I am not understanding why we should do /nn or /n/..can you please explain

Comment: Because you don't want to use the THEN expression if the orderstatus doesn't have a date. 2 of the 3 rows you mentioned all have one thing in common: The don't have a date. Date meaning m/d/yy or mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy. The 3rd row that's erroring has the date at the end and not immediately after the SLD. So you'll need to account for that, too. Multiple items to solve here.

Comment: @Isolated: if the date is not present immediately after *SLD then I can just pickup the orddate ..I have modified my input table

Comment: Hi @isolated ...Should it look like this...CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("ORDERSTATUS",'^\\/nn') <> 0 or CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("ORDERSTATUS",'^\\/n/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle MM separately since TO_DATE requires specific date format.

```
SELECT *
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR("ORDERSTATUS", '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') AS extracted_date
     , CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("ORDERSTATUS", '^\\*SLD') <> 0 THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN LEN(SPLIT_PART(extracted_date, '/', 3)) = 2 THEN TO_DATE(extracted_date, 'MM/DD/YY')
                   WHEN LEN(SPLIT_PART(extracted_date, '/', 3)) = 4 THEN TO_DATE(extracted_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                   END
    END                                                                 AS ORDERDATE
```

**Test Out with rows you provided**

```
WITH ord AS (SELECT '*SLD 05/11/2022' AS orderstatus
             UNION
             SELECT '37141 SLD BAM'
             UNION
             SELECT '*SLD 5/14/22 Heman'
             UNION
             SELECT '37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA'
             UNION
             SELECT '*SLD BOBBY LANE IDS#2347509'
             UNION
             SELECT '*SLD F.CHAPMAN/S.GUNN 5/31/22'
             UNION
             SELECT '*SLD S.STONE STK# 39391 40183')
SELECT *
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR("ORDERSTATUS", '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') AS extracted_date
     , CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("ORDERSTATUS", '^\\*SLD') <> 0 THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN LEN(SPLIT_PART(extracted_date, '/', 3)) = 2 THEN TO_DATE(extracted_date, 'MM/DD/YY')
                   WHEN LEN(SPLIT_PART(extracted_date, '/', 3)) = 4 THEN TO_DATE(extracted_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                   END
    END                                                                 AS ORDERDATE
FROM ord
```

**Output**

| orderstatus | extracted_date | orderdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *SLD 05/11/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 2022-05-11 |
| *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 5/14/22 | 2022-05-14 |
| *SLD BOBBY LANE IDS#2347509 |  | NULL |
| *SLD F.CHAPMAN/S.GUNN 5/31/22 | 5/31/22 | 2022-05-31 |
| *SLD S.STONE STK# 39391 40183 |  | NULL |
| 37141 SLD BAM |  | NULL |
| 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 5/18/22 | NULL |

Comment: Hi @Pirate X: Thank you so much for your response!..Just wondering why the orderdate is NULL for 4 rows ...It should be the orddate and for 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA also it should be the orddate

Comment: You can put 'ELSE DATE("ORDDATE")' in the CASE clause. That should give you what you're looking for. I didn't include it for simplicity.